# Create a Dockerfile from NiFi Docker Container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apache-nifi

I'm pretty new to using Docker. I'm needing to deploy a NiFi instance through my employer, but the internal service we need to use requires a Dockerfile, not an image.

The service we're using requires the Dockerfile because each time the repository we're using is updated, the service is pointed to the Dockerfile and initiates the build process from it, then runs/operates the container.

I've already set up the NiFi flow to how it needs to operate, I'm just unsure of how to get a Dockerfile from an already existing container (or if that is even possible?)

Comment: If you think you need an unmodified Docker Hub image, you could "build" a degenerate Dockerfile `FROM public-image:tag` and nothing else.  But typically you'd need to `COPY` things from your repository into the image as it gets updated.

Comment: This is what I just discovered and was the solution to my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking into this myself, apparently there is no real way to do it, but you can inspect the docker container and pretty much get all the commands used to create the container except the OS used which is easy to find, you can spawn a bash into the container and do something like `sudo uname -a`, which you can just take and make your own docker image with. Usually you can find it on github, though.

```
docker inspect <image>
```

or you can do it through the docker desktop UI

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dockerfile that is in NiFi source code, see in this directory: https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/main/nifi-docker/dockerhub